# Can you have variables within triple quotes? If so, how?

Tags: python, string, formatting

This is probably a  very simple question for some, but it has me stumped.  Can you use variables within python's triple-quotes?

In the following example, how do use variables in the text:

```
wash_clothes = 'tuesdays'
clean_dishes = 'never'

mystring =""" I like to wash clothes on %wash_clothes
I like to clean dishes %clean_dishes
"""

print(mystring)
```

I would like it to result in:

```
 I like to wash clothes on tuesdays
     I like to clean dishes never
```

If not what is the best way to handle large chunks of text where you need a couple variables, and there is a ton of text and special characters?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

One of the ways in Python 2 :

```
>>> mystring =""" I like to wash clothes on %s
... I like to clean dishes %s
... """
>>> wash_clothes = 'tuesdays'
>>> clean_dishes = 'never'
>>> 
>>> print mystring % (wash_clothes, clean_dishes)
 I like to wash clothes on tuesdays
I like to clean dishes never
```

Also look at string formatting

- http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string-formatting

Comment: That is perfect.  Thanks so much!  That is exactly what I was looking for! I don't exactly get how python knows which %s to replace with which variable, though.  Does it look at the order the variables appear in the following:  

print mystring % (wash_clothes, clean_dishes)

Comment: @XL : You can take a look at the other formatting technique for which I had provided the link but the example. The example was provided by NullUserException. You can use both the techniques.

Answer (score 93):

The preferred way of doing this is using [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) rather than the method using `%`:

> This method of string formatting is the new standard in Python 3.0, and should be preferred to the `%` formatting described in String Formatting Operations in new code.

Example:

```
wash_clothes = 'tuesdays'
clean_dishes = 'never'

mystring =""" I like to wash clothes on {0}
I like to clean dishes {1}
"""

print mystring.format(wash_clothes, clean_dishes)
```

Comment: and const string `{`, `}` can be escaped as `{{`, `}}`.

Comment: and if you would like to conditionally add it, you can do something like
`{0 if cond else ""}`

Comment: The preferred way is now using f-strings. Python has at least 3 ways of formatting strings for historical reasons.

Answer (score 91):

Yes! Starting from Python 3.6 you can use the `f` strings for this: They're interpolated in place, so `mystring` would have the desired value after the `mystring = ...` line:

```
wash_clothes = 'tuesdays'
clean_dishes = 'never'

mystring = f"""I like to wash clothes on {wash_clothes}
I like to clean dishes {clean_dishes}
"""

print(mystring)
```

Should you need to add a literal `{` or `}` in the string, you would just double it:

```
if use_squiggly:
    kind = 'squiggly'
else:
    kind = 'curly'

print(f"""The {kind} brackets are:
  - '{{', or the left {kind} bracket
  - '}}', or the right {kind} bracket
""")
```

would print, depending on the value of `use_squiggly`, either

```
The squiggly brackets are:
  - '{', or the left squiggly bracket
  - '}', or the right squiggly bracket
```

or

```
The curly brackets are:
  - '{', or the left curly bracket
  - '}', or the right curly bracket
```

Comment: sounds great - is there a possibility to change the delimiter from curly brackets {} to something else?

Comment: And simply note that to add single { or } inside the text (outside evaluation) you need it twice like so: {{ or }}

Comment: I always thought Python string interpolation was kludgy until this. Better late than never, eh?

Comment: didn't work as F made the remaning all texts  string

Answer (score 12):

Yes. I believe this will work.

`do_stuff = "Tuesday"`

`mystring = """I like to do stuff on %(tue)s""" % {'tue': do_stuff}`

EDIT: forgot an 's' in the format specifier.

Comment: If you're going to mark down an answer, please say why, so that we all can learn from the mistake.

Comment: This is great for repeated variables

Answer (score 10):

I think the simplest way is str.format() as others have said.

However, I thought I'd mention that Python has a [string.Template](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings) class starting in Python2.4.

Here's an example from the docs.

```
>>> from string import Template
>>> s = Template('$who likes $what')
>>> s.substitute(who='tim', what='kung pao')
'tim likes kung pao'
```

One of the reasons I like this is the use of a mapping instead of positional arguments.

Comment: That is an interesting approach.  I really don't like the positional arguments either as it may become tricky if you have a really large number of variables.  The only question that I have is whether this method is worthwhile if you have massive amounts of formatted text and special characters in the template string?

Comment: you can use positional arguments with `format`. `d = dict(foo=1, bar=2); "{foo} {bar}".format(**d)`

Comment: `string.Template` is orders of magnitude slower than other methods

Answer (score 2):

Also note that you don't need the intermediate variable:

```
name = "Alain"
print """
Hello %s
""" % (name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass multiple args in simple way

```
wash_clothes = 'tuesdays'
clean_dishes = 'never'
a=""" I like to wash clothes on %s I like to clean dishes %s"""%(wash_clothes,clean_dishes)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is real working code from my project. Uses 3 single quotes. note the use of single quotes with %s.

```
day = "2023-07-11"

df_t= spark.sql('''
    select * from db.article_events_ where yyyy_mm_dd < '%s'
    ''' %(day))
df_t.count()
```