# how to insert variables into Sqlite3 database

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

I'm not familiar with SQL(or python to be honest), and i was wondering how to add variables into tables. This is what i tried:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('TESTDB.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table(number real, txt text)''')
r=4
c.execute('''INSERT INTO table(r,'hello')''')
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

This doesn't work.I get the error, "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"How do i make the table insert the variable r??

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, can you have variables within triple quotes? If so, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877623/in-python-can-you-have-variables-within-triple-quotes-if-so-how)

Comment: Why is this tagged mysql?

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind values to *placeholders* in a prepared statement. See examples in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects).

Trying to build a query string on the fly with unknown values inserted directly in it is a great way to get a [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack and should be avoided.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you don't inject `r` properly into your query. This should work:

```
c.execute('''INSERT INTO table(''' + str(r) + ''','hello')''')
```

cheers