# How to call a list in a string?

Tags: python, string

I am a new to python programming and trying to understand how it works while editing a string file. I wanted to *call* either variables or lists or tuple in a string and solve the values and update the string file. Here is a simple example

```
t_list = ['c','d','e']


doc = '''
 domain ()
 :types a b c - objects
        f"{t_list}" - items
'''
doc_up = doc
```

I wanted my `doc_up` to be updated with values of list `t_list`. I referred to [PEP 498: Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498) but it doesn't work.

My output is like this:

```
'\n domain ()\n :types a b c - objects\n        f"{t_list}" - items\n'
```

I want my output to be like this:

```
 domain ()
 :types a b c - objects
        c d e - items
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877623/in-python-can-you-have-variables-within-triple-quotes-if-so-how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.format`. Remove `f"..."` from the string and leave just `{t_list}`, for example:

```
t_list = ["c", "d", "e"]


doc = """
 domain ()
 :types a b c - objects
        {t_list} - items
"""

doc_up = doc.format(t_list=" ".join(t_list))
print(doc_up)
```

Prints:

```
 domain ()
 :types a b c - objects
        c d e - items
```