# Insert value in a string with '''

Tags: python

I am trying to write a LaTex from a Python script:

```
n=4
content = r'''\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
the value of "n" is n
\end{document}
'''
```

How could I read the value of `n` inside of the command `r''' '''`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you have variables within triple quotes? If so, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877623/can-you-have-variables-within-triple-quotes-if-so-how)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`fstring`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) formating:
This is probably the easiest and recommended method.

For example:

```
n=4
content = rf'''\documentclass{{article}}

\begin{{document}}
the value of "n" is {n}
\end{{document}}
'''
print(content)
```

There is also the [`.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20format#str.format)

```
n=4
content = r'''\documentclass{{article}}

\begin{{document}}
the value of "n" is {0}
\end{{document}}
'''
content.format(n)
print(content)
```

There is the [printf style](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=printf#printf-style-string-formatting) formatting.

```
n=4
content = r'''\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
the value of "n" is %d
\end{document}
''' % n
print(content)
```

You can also concatenate different string sections together

```
n=4
content = r'''\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
the value of "n" is ''' + str(n) + ''' 
\end{document}
'''
print(content)
```