# PostgreSQL CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to create dataBase in Postgre SQL Python, i got an error: CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block. I have read that u need autocommit, but i already have it. What's the problem

```
try:
    with psycopg2.connect(
        host=host,
        user=rootUser,
        password=rootPassword,
    ) as connection:
        connection.autocommit = True
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(
                ("CREATE DATABASE " + db_name + """ WITH
                OWNER = """ + user + """ ENCODING = 'UTF8'
                CONNECTION LIMIT = -1
                IS_TEMPLATE = False;""")
            )
```

Comment: Not able to test currently but I would check the use of triple quotes on the create database part. Also I would normally format string to inject parameters e.g. q =””” abc {} ghi”””. Then q.format(‘def’). https://stackoverflow.com/a/3877647/12406828 

I’m wondering if it’s not resolving properly and creating two statements in the view of Postgres.

Comment: For reasons I don't understand, the `with psycopg2.connect(...) as connection:` construct seems to render the autocommit setting non-functional.  Defining and populating the "connection" variable the usual way does work.

Answer (score 0):

Since v2.9, `with conn` starts a transaction ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/941)), so it can't be used for actions like executing `CREATE DATABASE` which must be issued outside a transaction.

You can do it without using the context manager:

```py
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='postgres')
    conn.autocommit = True
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute('CREATE DATABASE foo')
finally:
    conn.close()
```

or like this

```
import contextlib

with contextlib.closing(psycopg2.connect(dbname='postgres')) as conn:
    conn.autocommit = True
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute('CREATE DATABASE foo')
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all you have to ensure that you are using a psycopg version that supports autocommit, i.e version 2.73 or later. Also you have to set `autocommit` to `True` before creating the cursor by modifying your code;

```
try:
    with psycopg2.connect(
        host=host,
        user=rootUser,
        password=rootPassword,
        autocommit=True,
    ) as connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(
                ("CREATE DATABASE " + db_name + """ WITH
                OWNER = """ + user + """ ENCODING = 'UTF8'
                CONNECTION LIMIT = -1
                IS_TEMPLATE = False;""")
            )
except psycopg2.Error as e:
    print("Error:", e)
```

Comment: Using autocommit as a connection parameter is not supported (not in 2.9.3 anyway)